# Wait for dynamically created Tasks until they completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

My program is creating some Tasks to do some work.
Now I want to wait for all tasks to complete before I will exit my program.

I know the `Task.WaitAll(...)` method but in my case I want to create some Tasks dynamically --> they don't exist when `Task.WaitAll()` is called.

My question now is:
how can I wait for all running Tasks until they are completed?

This is what I'm doing now.

It works but I want to be sure this is also a good way to do it.

```
public class Test
{
    public ConcurrentBag<Task> RunningTasks { get; set; } 

    public Test()
    {
        RunningTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
    }

    public void RunIt(){

        //...create some Tasks asynchronously so they may be created in a few seconds and add them to the list like
        //RunningTasks.Add(...);


        //Just wait until all tasks finished.
        var waitTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (RunningTasks.All(t => t.IsCompleted))
                    break;

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        waitTask.Wait();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Task.WhenAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) will take an array of `Task`, and the `ConcurrentBag<T>` supports the `ToArray()` extension method, so you can simply do:

```
await Task.WhenAll(RunningTasks.ToArray())
```

or if you don't want to use the `await` keyword:

```
Task.WhenAll(RunningTasks.ToArray()).Wait()
```

**UPDATE**

So if your `RunningTasks` is changing after the initial call you can do this pretty easily to handle it:

```
while(RunningTasks.Any(t=>!t.IsCompleted))
{
    Task.WhenAll(RunningTasks.ToArray());
}
```

The main benefit over your method is that this will yield the thread to other work while it waits, where your code will tie up the thread in a sleep state until all the tasks are completed.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer but in my case i will create Task inside other Tasks (I have some custom logic to create new Tasks) and the RunningTasks.ToArray()-Method is only adding the current Tasks to the WhenAll-Method. It will ignore Tasks that will be added to the RunningTasks list later.

Comment: @CodingGrillla: Your updated solution will case an OutOfMemory-Exception. So I guess i will use my solution. Anyway thanks for trying to help!!

Comment: @TobiasKoller Why would it cause an OutOfMemoryException?  I'll admit it isn't exactly the most memory efficient (multiple array allocations), but it shouldn't cause an exception.

Comment: I just added your lines and could see that my Unit-TestProcess is eating all the Memory and finally I got an outofmemory-exception. Don't know why, sorry.